# How to get passport back from employer without losing job?

Tags: job-change, employer-relations, student, uae

I am a Pakistani citizen working in a company located in the **UAE**. When the company provided me a visa they kept my passport. Now I want to apply for a study visa and to go for an interview I need a passport. I don't want to lose my job in this pandemic situation and the student visa interview does not guarantee a position so I need some advice on how to handle this carefully.
**Edit**: I simply asked and the employer hasn't created any issue in giving my passport back.
**Thanks All for suggestions**

Comment: Followin on Tom's comment, did you try asking for the passport? Or are there some factors that make you reluctant to even ask?

Comment: it is illegal but still, most of the companies are keeping passport otherwise they will not hire. and that's happened to me in my previous job.

Comment: @Shahid: Is there some government authority you can anonymously report your employer to? In my country that result in hefty fines, I don't know about the UAE, maybe someone can clarify this.

Comment: @Peter there are some labor laws but you will have a lot of trouble. like as an expat going to court instead of the job plus the plain to apply for study visa will also ruin if they will cancel my visa.

Comment: @Shahid: Is your goal to eventually leave the UAE? What about just waiting until the end of the pandemic and then applying for university?

Comment: How do you know you actually have a visa if they haven't given you your passport back?

Comment: @AlanDev I have Emirate ID and scanned passport having visa pasted.

Comment: Can you get a replacement for your 'lost' (or maybe it was stolen) passport?

Comment: @Peter the pandemic could last for years.

Comment: Couldn't you report your passport as stolen/missing and simply get one by mail? Your employer will probably never know about the passport being declared missing/stolen. If they find out, simply state ignorance that you forgot and was looking for it.

Comment: @Bwmat I think if I get a new passport it will go to the employer for visa pasting i am not sure but don't want to take the risk.

Comment: Why do they keep your passport? To prevent you from applying to other jobs?

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer to this question, since OP's problem has already been solved:

**1 - First, assume good intention**

I'd hardly believe someone is keeping your passport from you deliberately. But maybe, it was left on a locked drawer whose owner is now working from home, and maybe even moved away from the city so it's hard for him to simply give it back to you, hence he/she might simply not touch the subject until you do. Most likely, someone simply forgot they had your document.

If this is the case, nothing to worry about, any decent employee would ask you no questions as to why you want your passport back.

**2 - Second, assume soft and mostly passive misconduct**

Maybe they think you have no need for a passport, since you shouldn't be travelling nor applying for jobs/studies elsewhere. Heck what do they lose by keeping your passport for them while they can?

While I see some petty people thinking like this, they know they'd be crossing some serious lines by actually denying your passport. So they might (unrightfully) ask "why do you need your passport?" (the home-office worker away from town might also ask this, but he/she just justify the question and explain the situation before asking).

I suggest three options for your answer:

"Because it's mine, why else?"

"I need the passport to open a bank account in the US, I want to trade some stocks there, have you heard about XXX company?"

"I will totally forget this later, and I'm afraid this may be an issue in the future"

Any reasonable person should not argue with either of those responses. but then...

**3 - Identify willful misconduct**

If someone on HR is keeping your passport hostage, either to prevent you from doing something or due to some big laziness (see home office worker example), then this is willful misconduct. No company, anywhere in the world has the right to retain your passport.

If the problem was not solved by step 2, then act more seriously. If your company had a compliance program (which should be segregated from the management team) you should have channels to file a complain if you hold enough proof. Weight this against the next suggestion.

Personally, I would message the HR's person's boss with something like "Hey Joe/Jane, how've you been? Have you heard news about (HR person)? Is everything okay with him/her?". As the conversation proceeds (maybe the person is on vacation, or the hospital or whatever, but otherwise), you bring the passport issue "well, I've asked him/her about my passport and when and how should I retrieve it, we've talked, he/she asked why I needed it but the conversation stopped there".

For any decent manager, this is a loud and clear message that you think the HR person screwed up, but you just want your problem solved. And solved it should be by now. HR should tell you how to get your passport back, probably without you even asking. If not, just contact HR again asking for your passport and possibly ask the manager if the talk with the HR person has already taken place.

**4 - Pick your fights**

Now, we've reached the point where you can't really be casual and discreet about it. If the risk you take by exposing yourself is not worth the opportunity you'll be missing, then this might be the place to give up.

But, there are a few options you can still consider that may have different social costs depending on the customs of your country. One approach is: email HR person, with his/her boss copied, maybe even someone higher up, and list the dates of all conversations related to the topic. No need to detail what went on in each talk, simply say the subject of your passport being in company's possession has been addressed in all this opportunities and you just want it back. Some people might get offended by the attitude, but they've earned this at that point. Just make sure you are not in a rush (the earliest date should be at least two weeks prior to this e-mail).

Next, you might raise the fact that you suspect the company has lost your passport. Once you've cracked a reason such as this, people normally give up keeping it secret. Then demand that the company pays the cost of re-emitting it. Tell them you have no option now or later than to register a with the police that the passport is missing, and that claiming to have lost it might de considered defrauding on your part (or some local equivalent, but do check if the laws work like this where you live). This gives a very good reason for them to return your passport without asking questions as to why you want it back.

Finally, if even that fails, find a lawyer and get advice. You might get a court order to have the company forced to return your passport or explain in concrete terms what happened to it. Depending on local laws, there might be some short term immunity against retaliation that would prevent you from being fired (if you want to keep the job), or you can litigate for damages incurred by your lost opportunities (if you are okay with leaving and having a not-so-easy time getting your next job).

Comment: Unfortunately, keeping passports to keep workers from leaving is a thing in that part of the world.

Comment: Would you mind stating how much experience you have with the situation OP is in (eg Pakistani in UAE)?

Comment: @guest: Not sure if you wanted me or Loren to answer. As for me: I have no experience with the UAE or Pakistan whatsoever. I did mention at the beggining of the answer that OP's problem has already been solved (apparently, he was done on step 1 of my answer). This is a generic answer that should fit most people with a similar problem. That being said, Loren's comment getting more upvotes than my answer does raise my brows.

Comment: @Mefitico I can't speak for others who chose to upvote Loren's comment and not your answer, but I did so because your answer puts much too much weight on assumptions of good faith. It's great that in this particular case the employer *has* been willing to give OP their passport back, but as Loren notes, unscrupulous employers holding passports hostage is unfortunately a very common phenomenon in that part of the world, and you seemed much too quick to dismiss the possibility.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent : You have a valid point, but to clarify myself: Whatever one suspects the case to be, unless there exists solid evidence of willful misconduct or some well known precedent, I believe that the professional attitude is to act assuming no ill intention, and escalate as necessary. Notice that OPs condition is that he/she does not want to lose the job, and in general, one should avoid burning bridges. But also, notice that I did gave suggestions for the deliberate misconduct case.